# Split a list into three in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections, partitioning

I have the following data class:

```
data class Foo(val a: Int = 0, val b: Int = 0)
```

I have a list of `Foo`'s with the following structure:

```
[ Foo(a = 1), Foo(a = 2), ..., Foo(b = 22), Foo(a = 5), Foo(a = 6), ... ]
```

(a group of items with `a`'s, then one `b`, then `a`'s again)

I would like to split above list into three sub-lists like that:

1. `[ Foo(a = 1), Foo(a = 2), ...]`
2. `[ Foo(b = 22) ]`
3. `[ Foo(a = 5), Foo(a = 6), ...]`

---

1. sublist of elements that have non-zero `a` property
2. list of one element that has non-zero `b`
3. remaining sublist of elements that have non-zero `a` property

Is it possible to achieve using `groupBy` or `partition`?

Comment: Short answer: No. `partition` only returns two lists, and `groupBy` ignores ordering. `chunked` and `windowed` are the only two functions in `kotlin.collections` that return `List<List<T>>` but neither of those is appropriate either. I think you'll just have to write these 5 lines of code yourself ;)

Comment: how can  `Foo` be with one `a` or one `b`?

Comment: @IR42 it's just a property of `Foo` which I want to use for splitting, I wrote it that in pseudocode in order to be more concise

Comment: Yeah, I don’t understand the problem because you say you have a list of Foos, but it’s a list of numbers by letters. A Foo above is two numbers.

Comment: When you say that the first element of your list of Foos is `a = 1` what do you mean by that? Foo has an `a` and a `b` property. Same question applies for the split lists. What's `b = 22`?

Comment: You want to split your list where you "have a ``b``", right? Why are the ``Foo``s before that considered not to have a ``b``? Honestly it would be better if you just wrote out the list of ``Foos`` in full and the resulting lists you want

Comment: @Tenfour04 I added default properties, and expanded notation for sublists

Comment: @cactustictacs  I added default properties, and expanded notation for sublists

Comment: @al3c  I added default properties, and expanded notation for sublists

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. Once a Foo is instantiated, it has both an `a` and a `b`, regardless of whether it was constructed using a default or not.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes it has, my point is that I want to split the list into three parts, first items with non-zero a, then one non-zero b element, then sublist of remaining non-zero a's

Comment: Ah, you could have said that at the beginning. But what do you want to do if both values are zero, or if neither value is zero?

Comment: @Tenfour04 you can assume that this will never happen (I control what's in the list)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do it via `groupBy` or `partition`, because it is not possible to check the past state in those operations. However, you can do it via a fold operation and using mutable lists. Not sure if it fits to your needs but here it goes:

```java
    val input = listOf(Foo(a = 1), Foo(a = 2), Foo(b = 22), Foo(a = 5), Foo(a = 6))
    val output: List<List<Foo>> = input.fold(mutableListOf<MutableList<Foo>>(mutableListOf())) { acc, foo ->
        val lastList = acc.last()
        val appendToTheLastList =
            lastList.isEmpty() ||
                    (foo.a != 0 && lastList.last().a != 0) ||
                    (foo.b != 0 && lastList.last().b != 0)
        when {
            appendToTheLastList -> lastList.add(foo)
            else -> acc.add(mutableListOf(foo))
        }
        return@fold acc
    }

    println(output)
```

outputs:

> [[Foo(a=1, b=0), Foo(a=2, b=0)], [Foo(a=0, b=22)], [Foo(a=5, b=0),
> Foo(a=6, b=0)]]

**Note:** I have to point out that this solution is not better than a solution with regular loops.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to 1) ignore the first `Foo`s where `a=0`, 2) start collecting them when you see `Foo`s where `a` is non-zero, 3) when you hit a `Foo` where `a=0`, put that in another list, because `b` will be non-zero, 4) start collecting non-zero `a`'s again in a third list?

If that's what you want (this is an extremely specific thing you want and you haven't been clear about it at all) you could do it this way:

```
data class Foo(val a: Int, val b: Int)

val stuff = listOf(Foo(0,1), Foo(1,2), Foo(3,0), Foo(0, 4), Foo(0, 5), Foo(6, 1), Foo(0,7))

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun aIsZero(foo: Foo) = foo.a == 0

    // ignore initial zero a's if there are any
    with(stuff.dropWhile(::aIsZero)) {
        val bIndex = indexOfFirst(::aIsZero)
        val listOne = take(bIndex)
        val listTwo = listOf(elementAt(bIndex))
        val listThree = drop(bIndex+1).filterNot(::aIsZero)
    
        listOf(listOne, listTwo, listThree).forEach(::println)
    }
}
```

You can't use `partition` or `groupBy` because your predicate depends on the value of `a`, but also on whether it happens to represent that one element you want to put in the `b` list, and for the others whether they appear before or after that `b` element. Which you don't know before you start processing the list.

You could mess around with indices and stuff, but honestly your use case seems so specific that it's probably better to just do it imperatively instead of trying to cram it into a functional approach.